# terraform apply - how to use wildcard or range for indexes?

Tags: terraform

I have 10 virtual machines to be re-created.
I want to do it in 2 groups, first 5 machines [0-4] and second 5 machines [5-9]

```
terraform apply -replace=module.ci.azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[0-4]
```

But it does not work, says:

```
│ Index key must be followed by a closing bracket.
```

Is there any way to use a wildcard, or point a group of machines in general in command above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can specify ranges. On Linux, you can add a bash function such as from [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2182#issuecomment-898798893).

A slight modification should work,

```
terraform-replace () {
    sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | grep -o '# [^( ]* ' | grep '\.' | sed " s/^# /-replace '/; s/ $/'/; "
}
```

Then use it like this,

```
terraform plan | terraform-replace | grep 'azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm\[[0-4]\]' | xargs -r terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can pass a list of machines with single index value in each, separated by space. I suppose it is what it is.

Comment: Right, this is what my answer does

Comment: It is not necessary for you, I just find it useful to list targets, (if you would use the original from github).